# Reputation as a function of deleting your own answer

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-answers

Circumstance:

- See a question
- Give an answer
- Visit the same page two hours later
- Realize your answer is bad

What happens if you delete it? Does your reputation stay intact?

I read five other questions on this topic and didn't see this exact question answered.

Comment: Depends.  If one starts at 1 and continues to give bad answers (that _earn_ downvotes), she would still remain at 1.  Intact.

Answer (score 4):

When you delete your answer, you will loose any reputation you gain because of any up vote. If your answer has any downovte, you will gain those reputation back *(-2 for each downvote)*.

But if you just started answering and your reputation is 1 then your reputation will stay at 1 if you delete your post with down votes.

If you delete your answer with 3 or more up votes you will also get the badge for [Disciplined](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/37/disciplined)